# Intent.ACTION_SEND from react native

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, expo

I am attempting to send a .pdf to MobiPrint through an android intent. I have an example in Kotlin, but the problem is, I'm using React Native (inside of Expo) and haven't been able to translate it properly yet.

This is Kotlin code

```
val path: String? = _uri?.path
if(path != null) {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
    intent.setClassName(
        “com.mobiprintpro.retail.android“,
        “com.mobiprintpro.retail.android.ActivitySend“
    )
    intent.putExtra("companyCode", "")
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, _uri)
    intent.putExtra("fileUri", _uri.toString())
    intent.type = "application/pdf"
    intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY
    startActivity(intent)
}
```

Expo does have an intent launcher: `import * as IntentLauncher from 'expo-intent-launcher';`, however it does not seem to include Intent.ACTION_SEND. I'm not against ejecting from expo if need be, however I have yet to find a solution for React Native outside of Expo either. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.